# Quantum Discord and entropy

Tags: quantum-information, entropy

I'm trying to understand certain aspects of Quantum Discord. The idea is that a quantum system might have non-classical correlations despite it not being in an EPR-like state. So the discord is defined as:

> $D = I_t - I_c$

Where $I_t$ are the total correlations and $I_c$ are the classical correlations of the system. The classical correlations are defined via:

> $I_c(A|B)_{M_n} = S(A) - S(A|B)_{M_n}$

$M_n$ is the measure of m in B, that is given by the projector for the state $|n \rangle$ at subsystem B, ie: $\Pi_n^B = I \bigotimes \Pi_n$. And $S(A|B)_{M_n}$ is the conditional entropy, meaning the average over A after having measured {$M_n$} over B:

> $S(A|B)_{M_n}=\sum_m p_m S(\rho_{A|m})$

I'm having some problems understanding the expression for $\rho_{A|m}$ wich is the A density matrix after having measured m at B. 
Starting with the density matrix for the system $\rho_S$ the probability $p_m$ of measuring $M_n$ is given by the born rule: $p_m = Tr(\rho_S \Pi_m)$ but in my notes of the lecture I've that $p_m = Tr(\Pi_m \rho_S \Pi_m)$ and I don't seem to grasp why I need to sandwich the density matrix with two projectors and not by one.

Assuming that the sandwich is Ok, I would like to get the state of subsystem A after having measured m in B wich as usual is given by the partial trace:

> $Tr_B (\Pi_m \rho_S \Pi_m)$

But by the Schmidt decomposition theorem any state in AB can be written as:

> $|\Psi \rangle = \sum_k d_k |a_k \rangle |b_k \rangle$

Where $|a_k \rangle$ and $|b_k \rangle$ are a some of the elements of the basis of subsystem A and B. Once the projector $\Pi_m$ acts on $\rho_S$ all of the $|a_k \rangle$ go away because I'm putting an identity matrix in between them all and they are orthonormal. So it seems that after the sandwich of the density matrix I get something like $I \bigotimes |something_B \rangle$ and all the information of system A is lost. Is this correct or are there any faulty calculations in between?